# Error when trying to add Aspect to MongoTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-aop, spring-mongo

I'm trying to add aspect to the MongoTemplate Bean in Spring Rest Data this way:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

AspectConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"aspect"})
public class AspectConfig {
}
```

MongAspect.java

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MongoAspect {
    @AfterReturning("execution(* *.find(..)) && bean(mongoTemplate)")
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        String x = "aga";
    }
}
```

But I'm getting such error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'designRepositoryImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate repository.design.DesignRepositoryImpl.mt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 174 common frames omitted
```

What means that proxied bean couldn't been autowired.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Because I need to intercept all MongoTemplate.find calls.

Comment: The stack trace shows that it was unable to find any bean by the name of "mongoTemplate". Can you provide the config / class where mongoTemplate has been initialized?

Comment: @Jaiprakash If I remove MongoAspect then application successfully starts and bean mongoTemplate is being autowired.

Comment: Can you try with the annotation `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` ?

Comment: @corvax can you try @DependsOn("mongoTemplate"). Not sure, but it could be possible that the MongoAspect is being called before mongoTemplate could be bound.

Comment: @dunni That was it! Thank you! But I don't really understand what is this setting doing :(

Comment: I've added an answer with a more detailed explanation why this happens. If this answer helps you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @dunni Please add short recipe as @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) and explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class MongoTemplate implements two interfaces, `MongoOperations` and `ApplicationContextAware`. As soon as you add the aspect, Spring will create a proxy for this class, which will execute the aspect code. By default, if a class implements an interface, Spring will use JDK proxies, which only implement these interfaces, and not extend the class. So the proxy, which is then the Spring bean, doesn't have the type `MongoTemplate`, but only `MongoOperations`.

With the attribute in the following annotation you tell Spring, that it should use CGLib to create the proxy and it should extend the class, so the injection works also for fields with `MongoTemplate`:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```